# SSIS hangs at Pre-Execute - 50 percent complete sql command

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a data flow task that uses a OLE source and flows data into a OLE destination. There are no lookups or other processing that occur between the two tasks.

When I tell the source to use a table source the query works fine, but is incredibly slow because of locks on the source table.

When I use the following query as a "sql command" the ssis execution hangs at "Progress: Pre-Execute - 50 percent complete sql command"

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT

SELECT   [col1],[col2]
from [SourceSystemView]
```

So far I have tried:

- Enabling delay validation on both the task and connection
- Removing `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT` from the query

Executing the text query through ssms against the source system works fine.

Adding a top 100 clause to the query results in it running fine also, but the full query still fails to get past the pre execute. The source view has about 2,500,000 rows in, so I dont think it is anything that ssis wouldn't be able to cope with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as I was about to post this I found the problem (me being impatient!)

The query takes a long time to return any rows of data, so it actually appears to have hung on the "pre-execute", when in actual fact it has already sent the query to the source system and is waiting for data to be returned. Once data was coming back it suddenly marked itself as executing and was correctly showing the source task as being in progress.